# VSCode automatically (randomly?) marking whole project as untracked

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm not sure whether it has something to do with extensions or vs code settings configuration, but this is the first time I'm facing this.

It randomly lists all files as untracked.

Version: 1.86.2 (Universal)

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image]

List of all extensions that I'm using

[image]

Comment: I sometimes get this issue as well, I am usually reload vscode by pressing `Ctr`+ `Shift` + `P` -> "Developer: Reload Window"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with auto syncing Desktop (where my project folders are) to ICloud. After I disabled auto-syncing for these folders, everything started working as expected with no issues at all.

Or you can stop specific folders from being backed up to icloud by appending ".nosync" to their name. Eg. *Projects.nosync*

[image]